# Images from backend are not displayed

Tags: angular, typescript, image, nestjs

The image that I transfer from a nestjs backend to a angular frontend does not appear in the browser.

[image]

I send a query from the front to the backend containing the path to the file on the server (for example: "C:\MyFolder\MyFile.png"), which will read the image and send a stream back to the frontend. The frontend will then convert the blob to an image and set an img element's src attribute to the URL of the image.

## Backend

The backend code of the controller:

```js
@HttpCode(201)
@Get(':imageUrl')
@Header('Content-Type', 'image/png')
getFile(@Param('imageUrl')imageUrl: string) {
    imageUrl = atob(imageUrl);
    return fs.createReadStream(imageUrl);
}
```

## Frontend

Language selector ts code:

```js
currentLanguage: ApplicationLanguage;
availableLanguages: ApplicationLanguage[];

constructor(private readonly _languageProvider: CultureProviderService,
          private readonly _imageLoader: ImageService) {
    this.currentLanguage = _languageProvider._currentLanguage;
    _languageProvider.languageChanged.subscribe(
      newLanguage => {
        this.currentLanguage = newLanguage;
      }
    )
}
ngOnInit(): void {
    this._languageProvider.getAllAvailableLanguages().subscribe(
      (languages: ApplicationLanguage[]) => {
        this.availableLanguages = languages;
        languages.forEach((language: ApplicationLanguage) => {
          this._imageLoader.getImage(language.flagIcon).subscribe(
            imgBlob => {
              this._imageLoader.createImageFromBlob(imgBlob).then(
                result => {
                  language.image = result;
                },
                err => {
                  console.log(err);
                }
              )
            }
          );
        });
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      }
    );
}
```

The service that retrieves the image:

```js
constructor(private readonly _http: HttpClient,
          private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) { }

getImage(imageUrl: string): Observable<Blob> {
    return this._http.get(`${environment.machineServerUrl}/file/${btoa(imageUrl)}`, { responseType: 'blob' });
}

createImageFromBlob(imageUrl: Blob): Promise<SafeUrl> {
    return new Promise<SafeUrl>((resolve, reject) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener(
        "load",
        () => {
          resolve(this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(reader.result as string));
        }
      );

      if (imageUrl) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(imageUrl);
      } else {
        reject();
      }
    });
}
```

The HTML:

```html
<div>
  <mat-selection-list (selectionChange)="changeLanguage($event)"
                      [multiple]="false">
    <mat-list-option  *ngFor="let language of availableLanguages"
                      [value]="language"  [selected] ="isSelected(language)">
      <img [src]="language.image" height="70px" width="70px" alt="Flag">
    </mat-list-option>
  </mat-selection-list>
</div>
```

Did I do something wrong? Is something missing?

### Edit:

### The solution thanks to the accepted answer

First, nestjs version needed to be upgraded to v8+: nest update --force. Unfortunately it failed for my project, so I deleted dist, node_modules and package-lock.json, created a new nestjs project using CLI v8+ and used the generated package.json file to upgrade the project.

Then, updated the controller's code to use `StreamableFile` as suggested in the accepted answer:

```js
@HttpCode(201)
@Get(':imageUrl')
@Header('Content-Type', 'image/png')
getFile(@Param('imageUrl')imageUrl: string): StreamableFile {
  imageUrl = Buffer.from(imageUrl, 'base64').toString();

  const file = createReadStream(imageUrl);
  return new StreamableFile(file);
}
```

Official resource: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to be returning a stream, you'd need to do something like

```js
@HttpCode(201)
@Get(':imageUrl')
@Header('Content-Type', 'image/png')
getFile(@Param('imageUrl')imageUrl: string, @Res() res: e.Response) {
    imageUrl = atob(imageUrl);
    return fs.createReadStream(imageUrl).pipe(res);
}
```

If you're using Nest v8, you can use the [StreamableFile](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files) and do something like

```js
@HttpCode(201)
@Get(':imageUrl')
@Header('Content-Type', 'image/png')
getFile(@Param('imageUrl')imageUrl: string, @Res() res: e.Response) {
    imageUrl = atob(imageUrl);
    return new StreamableFile(fs.createReadStream(imageUrl));
```

And Nest will handle calling the `.pipe(res)` for you under the hood

Comment: You rock, thank you! I'll include the final controller code at the end of the post. Upgrading nestjs to v8 was a bit tricky because the automatic upgrade failed, so I edited the package.json, taking a new nestjs app v8 as model. It seems that your snippets have a small typo on the "res" argument, the "e." does not exist.

Comment: `e` is what I was using as an alias for `express` as in `import * as e from 'express'` so you could then type it as `e.Response`. Just helps minimize variable collision